# Will content observer loose it's state when the content provider process went down and comes up?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, contentobserver

Consider two apps (A, B) and here A has a content provider and B is interested in listening to the changes in content provider so B registered a content observer. When the process under which A runs gets killed and recreated will the content observer registered by B will loose it's state and no longer valid? Is my understanding correct?

If yes, Is there any way for B to tell A that it's process is alive now?

Comment: Anyone has experience with that and can answer?